# Examples of genus 1 curves that are not elliptic

Tags: algebraic-topology, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Every elliptic curve over a field $K$ can be mapped to a smooth, projective genus 1 curve (also defined over $K$) with a $K$-rational point, and vice versa. As I understand it, curves *without* said $K$-rational points can *never* be mapped to elliptic curves (since clearly then the elliptic curve group law cannot be established).

I'm trying to think of an example of an affine curve whose genus is $1$, but which is not also an elliptic curve. I know that the Riemann-Roch theorem gives:

$$g = \frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2} - s$$

Some searching online yielded the curve $y^{2}=x^{5}-x$, however I'm relatively certain that this Riemann-Roch gives $g = 6$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$, not $1$.

**What are some examples of affine genus $1$ curves that are not also elliptic curves?**

Comment: As a note, the curve $y^2 = x^5 - x$ has genus $2$, not $6$. This can be shown by applying the Riemann-Hurwitz Theorem to the projection map $(x,y) \mapsto x$.

Comment: What is your definition of "elliptic curve"?

Answer (score 3):

The following are classical examples of genus $1$ curves that are not elliptic curves over $\Bbb{Q}$:

$1.$ $C : 3X^3 + 4Y^3 + 5Z^3 = 0$ in $\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{Q}}$ (Selmer)

$2.$ Compactification of an affine curve $2y^2 = x^4 - 17$ in $\mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{Q}}$(Lind)

You can prove that these curves have genus $1$, but they do not have $\mathbb{Q}$-rational points.

I will explain each of the curves in more detail.

$1.$ Indeed, $3X^3+4Y^3+5Z^3=0$ is a torsor of an elliptic curve $E: X^3+Y^3+60Z^3=0$(This has a rational point $[1:-1:0]$).You can prove $C(\Bbb{Q})=\emptyset$ by showing that the rank of $E/\Bbb{Q}$ is $0$.This kind of discussion is detailed in Cassels''Lectures on elliptic curves'.

$2.$ Note that projective closure of this affine curve in $\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{Q}}$ has singular point at infinity $[0:1:0]$, thus we take projective closure　in $\mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{Q}}$ not in$\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{Q}}$.The point at infinity contains $\sqrt{2}$ in its coordinate, so there are no $\Bbb{Q}$-rational point at infinity. Also, you can check elementary the affine curve does not have $\Bbb{Q}$ rational points(cf.Chapter Ⅹ of Silverman's 'The arithmetic of elliptic curves'). You can also use Brauer-Manin obstruction to prove the affine curve does not have $\Bbb{Q}$-rational points by computing Hilbert symbol.

The equation $y^2 = -x^4 - 1$ in Alex B.'s answer provides a simpler example in response to this question. The two examples in my answer illustrate the so-called counterexample to local-global principle for genus $1$ curves.

Comment: @Piquito, what is your definition of an elliptic curve? The definition I am using is that of a genus 1 curve with a base point (see Silverman's book). The crucial point is that the curve defined by $3x^3 + 4y^3 + 5z^3 = 0$ is not an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ but is an elliptic curve over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Although $3x^3 + 4y^3 + 5z^3 = 0$ describes a smooth curve, it does not have any $\mathbb{Q}$-rational points.This definition becomes meaningful if we consider the Tate-Shafarevich group as a set of elliptic curves and a counterexample to the local-global principle.

Comment: @Piquito  Your first statement is false. For example, as commented in my answer, $X^3+Y^3+60Z^3=0$ is rank $0$ elliptic curve over $\Bbb{Q}$  and it is an elliptic curve over $\Bbb{Q}$ because it has a base point $[1:-1:0]$.

Comment: Okay Pont. I was wrong as you say. I have remembered that the cubics can be either of genus $0$ or genus $1$ and its are elliptic when the genus is $1$ forgetting the essential fact of  a  rational point playing as zero (can be any other than the mainly used , the point at infinity. I am going to be $86$ years old and this makes me make mistakes frequently. By the way, your $3x^3+4y^3=-5z^3$ is equivalent to
$$[9(3x^3)(4y^3)^2+(4y^3-3x^3)^3]^3+[9(3x^3)^2(4y^3)-(4y^3-3x^3)^3]^3=60[-3((3x^3)^2+83x^3)(4y^3)+(4y^3)^2]^3(xyz)^3$$ as you can verify (suite)

Comment: if you don't believe it. This for showing you that I am diminished by my age but not completely lost.

Comment: @Piquito If you consider a genus 1 curve with no rational points as an elliptic curve, you cannot introduce a group structure on it since being a group requires the existence of an identity element. Then you cannot define   Galois cohomology of elliptic curves and so on.

Comment: Obvious that the group law is the reason of being of elliptic curves: all the great open problems in this topic are in relation with.

Comment: @Piquito I would like to inquire about the definition of elliptic curves. If it is defined as a 'genus 1 curve with a base point,' I kindly request that you acknowledge the oversight and consider removing your initial comment, which may have come across as aggressive.

Comment: Aggressive, dear friend Pont, I think is when somebody put  unjust downvotes. When I wrotte my first comment, I was  absolutely convinced that my mistake was true but I did not put a downvote because I had seen an honest job in your answer. I remove my initial comment. Regards.

Comment: Hi  friend. So cubic's Selmer $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3=0$ becomes elliptic over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]3)$, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ and $\Bbb Q\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac75}\right)$. Not at all evident the rank equal $0$ because for example for all $A$ integer cube-free,  the cubic $x^3+y^3=Az^3$, is elliptic over $\Bbb Q$ and  always has an infinity of quadratic points whatever its rank be. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Consider an equation of the form $y^2=f(x)=a_0x^4+a_1x^3+\cdots+a_4$, where $a_i\in \mathbb{Q}$. If the discriminant of the quartic is non-zero, then this defines a smooth curve of genus $1$. However, you have to be careful with what that means: if you projectivise this naively, i.e. you treat this as a curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$, then it is easy to check that the point at infinity will be singular.

On the other hand, it is a general fact that there is a unique (up to isomorphism) smooth curve whose function field is $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)/(y^2-f(x))$. It's just that the curve does not embed as a smooth curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$. It does, however, embed as a smooth curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$ via $[X_0,X_1,X_2,X_3] = [1,x,y,x^2]$. It turns out that this projective curve has the affine piece $X_0\neq 0$ described by the above equation, and the only missing points are $[0,0,\pm\sqrt{a_0},1]$. This is explained in detail in Silverman, The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, Chapter II, Example 2.5.1.

Now, if $a_0$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}$, then those two points at infinity will not be rational points; and it is easy to arrange $f(x)$ in such a way that the affine piece will also not have any rational points, e.g. by making sure that it has no points over some completion of $\mathbb{Q}$. A very simple example: take $f(x) = -x^4 - 1$. Since $-1$ is not a rational square, the points at infinity, $[0,0,\pm\sqrt{-1},1]$, are not defined over $\mathbb{Q}$; and the affine piece certainly has no rational points, since it does not even have real points: $f(x)$ is negative for all $x$, so cannot be equal to $y^2$ for any real $y$.

The two examples in Pont's answer are more complicated: they are "notorious" for having points over all completions of $\mathbb{Q}$, but none over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is then necessarily harder to prove.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-Poincaré has proven in "Sur les proprietés arithmétiques des courbes algébriques. Jour. Math. pures et appliquées **7**, pages 161-233 (1901)" **that every curve with rational coefficients of degree greater than $3$ and genus $1$ is (birationally) equivalent to a cubic of genus $1$**.

In the same way that Hilbert and Hurwitz had proven that any curve defined by a polynomial of degree $n$, with rational coefficients and genus $0$, is equivalent to another curve of degree $n-2$ and genus $0$. Then if the degree is odd the curve is equivalent to a line and have infinitely many rational point and if the curve has even degree it is equivalent to a conic. (Look for this to the book "Diophantine equations" by Mordell (1969).

Hilbert and Hurwitz have closed, with the metioned theorem, the study of genus $0$ and the great importance of elliptic curves, from this perspective, will be that it will close the study of curves of genus $1$. Unfortunately the topic of elliptic curves is far from reach this goal.

Comment: A very celebrated theorem (I have forget the author) ensures that if the genus is greater than $1$ then the curve can have only a finite number of rational points. So it is also closed the study of curves of genus $\ge2$ similarly to what happen with genus $0$ from the perspective of rational points for genus $0$ and greater than $1$. It remains to solve the problem of rational points for genus $1$ which depens of elliptic curves. (Sorry for bad English)

Comment: I remembered few minutes after my answer that "the author" is G. Faltings (Fields Medal) but I did not added what I say now.